# Трактовка записи списков

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день!
Самостоятельно изучаю [python](/questions/tagged/python) прошу помощи более опытных товарищей разобраться – почему в коде из учебного примера (сливаются два списка и сортируются по возрастанию) допускается как запись

```
c += [b[j]] или c += [a[i]]
```

так и

```
c += a[i:] + b[j:]
```

В первом случае к пустому списку `c` добавляется элемент нового списка `b`
т.е.

```
c += [b[j]]  # все в квадратных скобках.
```

Почему во втором случае не будет работать запись?

```
c += [a[i:]] + [b[j:]]
```

Или это по причине того, что изначально задаётся диапазон (двоеточие)?

Спасибо за ответ

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6]

c = []
i = j = 0
while len(a) > i and len(b) > j:
     if a[i] > b[j]:
         c += [b[j]]
         j += 1
     else:
         c += [a[i]]
         i += 1
c += a[i:] + b[j:]
print(c)
```

Comment: Добрый день! Благодарю за ответы. Меня изначально немного смутила запись этого кода. Ведь если взять и просто проверить:         b = [2, 4, 6]

i = j = 0

1) print(b[i]) - вывод 2, т.е. нулевой элемент списка в виде числа
2) print(b[i:]) - вывод  [2, 4, 6], т.е. весь список
3) print([b[i]]) - вывод [2], т.е. список из одного нулевого элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательная книжка **Python, к вершинам мастерства**, там есть описание работы списков и не только. Все примеры Вашего кода будут работать, не сработает такой вариант (при условии, что `b[i]` не является вложенным списком или итерируемым объектом):

```
c += b[i]  # в отличии от c += [b[i]]
```

По причине конкатенации разных типов данных. Из ваших примеров в первом случае добавляется не *элемент нового списка `b`* а сливаются 2 списка: пустой список `c` и список с `i-тым` эл-том `[b[i]]` (может так проще - `list(b[i])`). Т.е. Ваш пример

```
c += [a[i:]] + [b[j:]]
```

будет работать, но он создаст список списков.
Вот почитайте: [habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/89456/), [из доков на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html)

Comment: Но если в b[i] лежит список то "c += b[i]" сработает

Comment: @AndrioSkur да, сработает, ща поправлю ;)